# JSplumb scrollable container

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsplumb

I'm trying to make a JSPlumb application somewhat like the demo [here](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/draggableConnectors/index.html), where the container element scrolls when you drag an item towards the edge of the screen. So far I have [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/m5eurfe6/), where the elements are draggable, but they are constrained by the container around it, greatly limiting how many of those elements can be on the screen.

I initiate the draggables with this snippet. Perhaps there's a scrollable attribute here that works?

```
jsPlumb.draggable(newState, {
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

I cannot for the life of me find out the what exactly makes the other one scroll, I tried changing the css and adding some jqueryUI attributes to the draggable object, but to no avail.

Does anyone with more JSPlumb experience have an idea on how I can make the container expand?

TLDR:
How to make [my draggables](https://jsfiddle.net/m5eurfe6/) scroll like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/m5eurfe6/)

Comment: I may be on the verge of figuring it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got the answer, It was a CSS thing. I looked closely for the CSS at the demo and found these two classes.

```
.jtk-surface {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    touch-action:none;
}
.jtk-surface-nopan {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Once I added these classes to my container div and removed the "container" property from the draggable init, it worked!

```
jsPlumb.draggable(newState, {

});
```

Check out the working pastebin [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m5eurfe6/1/)!

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks for following up on your discoveries with this!